# C++ std::map memory leak

Tags: c++, dictionary, std

I am having problems with a memory leak.  I have the following code:

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include <Map>

typedef struct _OUTPUT_HANDLER
{
  unsigned short outCnt;

  _OUTPUT_HANDLER()
    : outCnt(0)
  {}
} OUTPUT_HANDLER, *POUTPUT_HANDLER;

typedef std::map<unsigned long, OUTPUT_HANDLER *>outDataMap;
outDataMap outData;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR *argv[])
{
  if (!outData.empty())
  {
    POUTPUT_HANDLER oHandler;

    for (outDataMap::const_iterator dataOut = outData.begin(); dataOut != outData.end(); dataOut++)
    {
      oHandler = dataOut->second;
      delete[] oHandler;
    }
    outData.clear();
  }

  _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();

  return 0;
}
```

When I run it and get to the line _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks(); I get the following leaks:

```
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
{221} normal block at 0x0017B9E0, 24 bytes long.
 Data: <                > E0 B9 17 00 E0 B9 17 00 E0 B9 17 00 CD CD CD CD 
{220} normal block at 0x0017B998, 8 bytes long.
 Data: <  8     > A0 01 38 01 00 00 00 00 
Object dump complete.
```

I would appreciate any help with fixing this.

Comment: You are checking for memory leaks before `outData` has been destructed.

Comment: All identifiers starting with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter and all identifiers at the global scope starting with an underscore are reserved. `_OUTPUT_HANDLER` is a reserved identifier and can't be used. See [reserved identifiers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword).

Comment: You better stop using `typedef struct` in C++ (if they stop to use it in C it would be not bad either)